# Draw snake around the rectangular node

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations

I want to draw the "coiled snake " around the rectangle named "Obstacle". The rectangle consist of node "O". I could not figure it out as I am new to tikz. can anyone give me good suggestion in this?
Thanks in Advance

Here is the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{snakes}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{block} = [draw,rounded corners,thin,fill= gray!20,  rectangle,   thick,align=center]
 % Draw axes
 % \node (0,0)(a) {$\theta$}
 \draw [<->,thick] (0,2) node (yaxis) [above] {$y$}
    |- (2,0) node (xaxis) [right] {$x$};
%\draw [gray](0,0)+(0.5,0)arc(0:45:0.5); 
%\path (0,0)++ (22.5:0.7)node{$\theta$};
% Draw two intersecting lines

 \draw (1.2,1.2)coordinate(a_2);
%Draw vehicle
\draw [rotate =20](a_2)+(0.5,0)coordinate(V_c)node[block,minimum width=28,minimum height=18, rotate=20](a){};
\draw[snake=coil,](a)++(45:3)node[block,rotate=45,segment aspect=10,,minimum height=50,font =\large](O){Obstacle};

%Draw body axis
 \draw [->,rotate =20,thick] (V_c) -- ++(0,0.7)node[rotate=20](yaxis)[above]{$y_{b}$};
% \draw [->,rotate =45,thick] (V_c)++(-0.22,0.5) -- ++(0,0.7)node[rotate=45](yaxis)[above]{$v_{y}$};
  \draw [->,rotate =20,thick] (V_c) -- ++(0.8,0)node[rotate=20](yaxis)[below]{$x_{b}$};
  %draw Dimension of distance to obstacle
  \draw[dashed,rotate=45] (a.22) -- (O);
  \draw[snake=brace,raise snake=2pt,gap around snake =2pt,rotate=45] (a.22) -- (O);%for curly bracket
  \path (V_c)+(0.5,0)--coordinate(L)(O);
  \draw [rotate =45] (L)+(0.1,0.5) node[rotate=45]{$L_i$};
  \draw[->](a.10)--+(45:0.5)node[rotate=45,below]{$v$};
 \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally, for these purposes it is necessary to use the so called *late options* (see 16.14 Late Code and Late Options on the pgfmanual). This is a proof of concept exploiting `append after command`:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz,png]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\tikzset{block/.style={draw,rounded corners,thin,fill= gray!20,rectangle,thick,align=center}}
\tikzset{decorate this node/.style={
    append after command={
      \pgfextra{
        \draw[decoration type,decorate,#1](\tikzlastnode.south west)rectangle(\tikzlastnode.north east);
      }
    }
  },
  decoration type/.style={
    decoration={coil,raise=4pt,amplitude=1pt,segment length=6pt}
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[block,rotate=45,segment aspect=10,minimum height=50,font =\large,decorate this node={rotate=45}] (O) at(0,0) {Obstacle};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

> **Some remarks**

The `snakes` library has been superseeded by `decorations`. Moreover, I switched the deprecated `tikzstyle` into `tikzset` as per [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles).

Finally, for what concern the style `decorate this node`, be carefull to keep consistence with the transformations you apply to the node: see the option `rotate=45` passed also to the style.

Comment: In my opinion, a postaction with raised decoration on the node path would make things slightly easier.

Comment: I remember some problems of `dimension too large`by applying a postaction directly to the node from trials with smartdiagram. That's why I preferred this approach.

Comment: I guess if you make this node smaller same problem would pop up but I agree it's not failproof.